# How to disable "Wi-Fi disconnected" dialogue?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, huawei-g300

I have Huawei **U8815** aka **Ascend G300** with **Android 4.0.3**.

When I disable Wi-Fi connectivity or I'm out of range of Wi-Fi network I receive question which after translation means more or less "Further access to internet will cause network traffic. Continue?" an two answers: "Cancel" and "OK". If I press "OK" then mobile internet will be enabled, if I click "Cancel" mobile internet is disabled. Sometimes this dialogue is lost between other applications and/or by click somewhere else. In this cause, by default mobile internet is disabled.

I would like to have always enabled mobile internet. Unfortunately this dialogue don't have default option to pick. Is there any way to disable it, or pick default answer to "OK"?

Comment: Can't you just enable `System Settings->More->Mobile Networks->Check the data enabled option`?

Comment: This dialogue is overwriting this settings option.